# Object being called with wrong properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently building a website like PCPartPicker but for watercooling parts for a school project. I dove in and I am having some issues. The most important on being this:
Here is my object constructor to start

```
var cpuCollection = [];
var myComputer = [];
function CPU(frequency,cores,socket,name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.frequency = frequency;
    this.cores = cores;
    this.socket = socket;

    cpuCollection.push(this);
}

var i75930k = new CPU(3.6, 6, 2011.3, "i7 5930k");  
var i54690k = new CPU(3.6, 4, 1150, "i5 4960k");`
```

After I built the object constructor I made some test objects using real computer parts.

In my HTML I have drop down menus that are populated by the objects on load using this code:

```
$(cpuCollection).each(function() {
    $('#cpusel').append($("<option> " + this.name + "</option>"))
});
```

From there I wanted to make it so that when an option was selected in the dropdown the proper object would be pushed into the `myCPU` var for compatibility testing in another function. The code I used to accomplish this is as follows:

```
 $('#cpusel').change(function() {
    myCPU = new CPU();
    $(cpuCollection).each(function(){
       if(this.name = $('#cpusel :selected').text()) {
          myCPU = this;
       }
    });
 });
```

Unfortunately this code currently isn't working and is telling me that `myCPU.socket` is `1150` when the `i75930k` is selected when it really should be `2011.3`. I am getting to wits end here and want to make some progress.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Edit: I fixed the equals sign issue and now I am thinking that the problem may be stemming from the way I push the objects into the cpuCollection array. When I try and log cpuCollection I get [CPU, CPU] which is obviously not what I want. How can I push the CPU objects on creation into cpuCollection with all of their properties intact.

Comment: You mean `this.name ===` rather than `this.name =`.

Comment: Check out my solution - should be helpful to understand how you can fix and optimize your code. Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your if() statement:

```
$('#cpusel').change(function() {
myCPU = new CPU();
$(cpuCollection).each(function(){
   if(this.name === $('#cpusel :selected').text()) {
      myCPU = this;
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Rowan, unfortunatly I am now getting an error stating that myCPU is undefined. Let me do some debugging quickly.

Comment: ohh, yea, try a 'var myCPU'

Answer (score 0):

So, there were a few issues with some of your logic/syntax, and I will try to address them individually so you can better understand how I got a working solution:

1) You are pushing the element to an array from inside your object definition. This is typically bad practice, as it is not reusable, and will throw an error if an array called `cpuCollection` is not defined prior to the instantiation of that instance of the CPU object. It is better to say `cpuCollection.push(new CPU(...));`

2) When you append the options to the dropdown list, you should add the `value` property as well, so you can more easily grab the value in #3

3) If you set the value propery on the `<option>` elements, there is no need to look for the text of the selected option, you can simplify your selector to `$('#cpusel').val()`

4) There is no need to wrap your arrays in a jQuery object by saying `$(cpuCollection).each(...)`, you can (and should) use the built-in vanilla javascript array operations.

5) I changed your `.each()` in the change handler to be a `.some()` this is because when you return true from `.some()` it stops any further iteration, which is what you want. Previously, it would continue to loop to the end, even if it already found the matching CPU.

6) I added a myCPU variable and instantiated it to null, so if you are running in strict mode, your change handler wouldn't throw an error for the variable not having been previously defined.

7) Your logic in your if statement was doing an assignment, rather than a comparison because you used `=` instead of `== or ===`, simple mistake.

Hope this helps!

```js
var cpuCollection = [];
var myComputer = [];
var myCPU = null;
function CPU(frequency,cores,socket,name) {
  this.name = name;
  this.frequency = frequency;
  this.cores = cores;
  this.socket = socket;
}

cpuCollection.push(new CPU(3.6, 6, 2011.3, "i7 5930k"));  
cpuCollection.push(new CPU(3.6, 4, 1150, "i5 4960k"));

cpuCollection.forEach(function(cpu, index) {
  $('#cpusel').append($('<option value="'+ cpu.name + '">'  + cpu.name + '</option>'))
});

$('#cpusel').change(function() {
  myCPU = new CPU();
  cpuCollection.some(function(cpu, index){
    if(cpu.name === $('#cpusel').val()) {
      myCPU = cpu;
      return true;
    }
  });
  console.log(myCPU);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cpusel"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is simple way(s) :

```
var cpuCollection = [];
var myComputer = [];

function CPU(frequency,cores,socket,name) {
    cpuCollection.push({
        name:      name,
        frequency: frequency,
        cores:     cores,
        socket:    socket
    });
}

var i75930k = CPU(3.6, 6, 2011.3, "i7 5930k");  
var i54690k = CPU(3.6, 4, 1150,   "i5 4960k");

$(cpuCollection).each(function(i,cpu) {
    var option = $('<option/>').html(cpu.name).data('cpu',cpu);
    $('#cpusel').append(option);
});

$('#cpusel').change(function() {

    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected'); 
    var text = $(selected).text();
    var myCPU;

    // You can simply use : myCPU = $(selected).data("cpu")
    console.log('via data:',$(selected).data("cpu"));

    $(cpuCollection).each(function(i,cpu){
        if($.trim(cpu.name) == $.trim(text)) {
           myCPU = cpu;
           // return false; ==> break the each();
        }
    });
    console.log('via each:',myCPU);
});
```

See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8vfdojbk/).